# How to speed up docker images building of c++ project with external c++ libraries?

Tags: docker, cmake, docker-compose

Simplified project structure:

```
orka_engine
├── orka_engine_preprocessing
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── src
│       └── main.cc
├── super_build
│    └── CMakeList.txt
└── lib
     └── // external checked out libs
```

with `super_build/CMakeList.txt` listing every external lib and every subdirectory in the project as external project with hardcoded path to it.

Right now the way to build the project is to

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ../super_build
make
```

and this works fine-ish.

Problems start when I try to dockerise this project. cmake for super_build refuses to run without source code present and this causes it to recompile external libraries on every update to source.

Relevant lines from Dockerfile

```
COPY ./orka_engine ./orka_engine

RUN mkdir ${BUILD_DIR} && \
    cd ${BUILD_DIR} && \
    cmake ../orka_engine/${CMAKE_TARGET} && \
    make -j 5
```

I would like to have external libs built before copying-in project source to cut down docker build times after the first.

I'm fairly open on how to achieve that.

Comment: why don't building/installing each dependencies in your docker one by one and use find_package(deps) than trying to build them in your "super-build" ?
in this case each deps are in a cached layer...
e.g. https://github.com/Mizux/Cbc/blob/master/ci/docker/ubuntu/Dockerfile

Answer (score 1):

in this case in your super_build cmake execute an other CMakeLists.txt containing your external project to build at configure time.

SuperBuild CMakeLists.txt

```
project(SuperBuild LANGUAGES NONE)

message(STATUS "Building: DEP_A...")

# Download, build, install DEP_A at configure time
configure_file(
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dep-a.CMakeLists.txt
    ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/dep-a/CMakeLists.txt)

execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -H. -Bproject_build -G "${CMAKE_GENERATOR}"
  RESULT_VARIABLE result
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/dep-a)
if(result)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "CMake step for dep-a failed: ${result}")
endif()

execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build project_build --config ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}
  RESULT_VARIABLE result
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/dep-a)
if(result)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Build step for dep-a failed: ${result}")
endif()
```

and dep-a.CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(dep-a-submodule NONE)

include(ExternalProject)

ExternalProject_Add(dep-a_project
  TMP_DIR "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/dep-a/tmp"
  STAMP_DIR "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/dep-a/stamp"
  DOWNLOAD_DIR "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/dep-a/download"
  SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/dep-a/source"
  BINARY_DIR "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/dep-a/build"

  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/dep-a/dep-a
  GIT_TAG "master"

  # UPDATE_COMMAND ""
  # PATCH_COMMAND git apply "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/patches/dep-a.patch"
  # CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
  CMAKE_ARGS
    -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/dependencies
    -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}
    -DBUILD_TESTING=OFF
  # BUILD_COMMAND ""
  # INSTALL_COMMAND ""
  TEST_COMMAND ""
)
```

take a look at https://github.com/Mizux/cmake-abseil/blob/install/README.md